# Extract title of a webpage using Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to extract title of a webpage using Python.
I followed the [instructions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/extract-title-from-a-webpage-using-python/) and got the title of most websites.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  
# target url
url = 'https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/'
  
# making requests instance
reqs = requests.get(url)
  
# using the BeaitifulSoup module
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')
  
# displaying the title
print("Title of the website is : ")
for title in soup.find_all('title'):
    print(title.get_text())
```

But I can't get title of website 1688.com. Example:
`https://detail.1688.com/offer/629606486448.html`

Can you help me to get the title of this page?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is because 1688.com includes a [robots.txt](https://detail.1688.com/robots.txt) most likely to prevent botting/webscraping. You can also see that [geeksforgeeks.com](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/robots.txt) allows webscraping. I would recommend either not attempting to scrape, or setting up a simple regex expression (I know, terrible) to search for the title.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. That means there's no way to get the title of prevent botting/webscraping sites like that?

Comment: How does robots.txt actually prevent webscraping?  Isn't honoring robots.txt optional (to be a good net citizen)?  I haven't done any webscraping before, but I always wondered about robots.txt.